# Как отследить время работы программы/процесса

Tags: c#, windows, процесс

Как отследить работу не моей программы, а программы на OC windows, или сколько работает процесс/служба?

Answer (score 5):

Находишь нужный тебе процесс и у него читаешь свойство [Process.StartTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.starttime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Зная время старта процесса и текущее время(DateTime.Now) вычитаешь одно из другого и получаешь время сколько процесс работал.

Например, так:

```
var minutes=(DateTime.Now - Process.GetProcessesByName("Word").First().StartTime).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: iluxa1810 , а пример кода можете прислать?